# event on selecting columns in jqGrid

Tags: jquery, jqgrid

Is there an event in jqGrid when a user uses the column dialog to add or remove columns.
If not, is there another way to track column change. I need this to persist selected columns when I show the grid on different pages.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Welllll.... You're showing the dialog yourself, right? So you're already in your own code?

I'm guessing that what you really mean is "when the user clicks 'Submit'?" If so, look at [afterSubmitForm](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:show_hide_columns).

Answer (score 0):

I think he means the column changing dialog from the jqGrid 3.6 demo.

Presently there is not an event for this, but there may still be a way. Grid method columnChooser accepts the following option in the jqGrid source:

```
"done" : function(perm) { if (perm) self.jqGrid("remapColumns", perm, true) },
```

Try providing your own version of the function (see the demo page for where to call this):

```
jQuery("#colch").jqGrid('columnChooser', {
   "done" : function(perm) { 
       if (perm) {
          jQuery("#colch").jqGrid("remapColumns", perm, true) 

          ( ... your code here ... )
       }
   }
});
```

Assuming this works, you could use the following code to figure out which columns are hidden:

```
var colModel = $("#mygrid").getGridParam("colModel");
for (var i = 0; i < colModel.length; i++){
    if (colModel[i].hidden) { 

        ... store away colModel.name somewhere ... 

    }
}
```