# How to track changes on jqGrid columns/layout/order?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jqgrid

I have a jqGrid that can be sorted by different columns both in ascending and descending order. Columns may be added or removed, and the order of the columns may be changed too. I need to detect when any of these properties have changed, in order to save the users preference.

Is there a way to catch these events? I've been looking at the problem for a few days but cant seem to find a way to do it without a "Save" button.. but I dont really like that solution..

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `onSortCol` event to detect if columns have been re-sorted.

Regarding adding/removing columns, [event on selecting columns in jqGrid](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1603747/event-on-selecting-columns-in-jqgrid) may be a good place to start.